# How do I upgrade Postgresql 9.6rc1 to Postgresql 9.6

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am fairly new to the PostgreSql scene so forgive me if this is a dumb question. I tried to search for this but, I kept finding only questions on upgrading from one version to another, like from 8.x to 9.x. But Just the other day I upgraded from 9.6beta4 to 9.6rc1 using dumpall, and today i see that 9.6 was released and don't really want to waste a day creating a dumpall file and restoring it. So I'd like to to know if there is an "inplace" upgrade, or do i still need to use dumpall again to go from 9.6rc1 to 9.6.

My main DB experience is with Firebird and Sql Server, and with those you don't need to do a backup restore when upgrading the DB software.

thanks,
Edward

Comment: `pg_upgrade` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgupgrade.html with the `--link` option does an in-place upgrade

Comment: I looked at this before. But that command is looking for oldbin & newbin, The yum/apt-get will install posgresql into same bin folder. also the manual says that the --link uses hard links. Does that mean that after the pg_upgrade we will have an olddatadir and newdatadir but the olddatadir will be linked to newdatadir?

Comment: Sorry I don't use Linux, no idea

Comment: In case someone comes across this thread. Here is a link to a blog post from 2ndQuadrant that describes the various types of PostgreSql upgrade procedures. http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/untangling-the-postgresql-upgrade/. If i had seen this blog post before i wouldn't have post this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dump/restore is only necessary if the catalog version has changed; that's `CATALOG_VERSION_NO` in `src/include/catalog/catversion.h`.

If you look at the [commit log of REL_9_6_STABLE](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=history;f=src/include/catalog/catversion.h;hb=refs/heads/REL9_6_STABLE), you'll see that the last change was on 2016-08-13.

So it should be safe to just update the software and restart the server.